# Embedding Records Nested 2 Layers in Ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data

I recently posted a question which was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226175/accessing-rails-relationships-with-ember-js) regarding accessing Rails Relationships.  The answer worked great and embedding records has worked fine for any single level nested attributes (The example in the preview question was 1 cohort has many boots).

What I can't get to work is adding a second level of Nesting (One cohort has many boots which each have many hubs).  I have the following extensions in my store.js.coffee file.

```
Plato.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend()

Plato.Store = DS.Store.extend(adapter: Plato.Adapter)

Plato.Adapter.map "Plato.Cohort", 
    boots:
    embedded: "always"

Plato.Adapter.map "Plato.Boot",
  hubs:
    embedded: "load"
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this (that is, the above code does not work)?

One problem I ran across is in my console when I run

```
var hub = App.Hub.find(1)
```

I get the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3031/hubs/1
```

When my ember routing is as follows

```
App.Router.map ()->
    this.resource('cohorts', ->
        this.resource('cohort', {path: '/:cohort_id'}, ->
        this.resource('boot', {path: '/boots/:boot_id'}, ->
                this.resource('hub', {path: '/hubs/:hub_id'})
      )
    )
  )
```

and my rails router is

```
  resources :cohorts do
    resources :boots do
      resources :hubs
    end
  end
```

Any idea why it is defaulting to the standard non-nested route?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `/` prefix from the nested route paths.

```
App.Router.map ()->
  this.resource('cohorts', ->
    this.resource('cohort', {path: ':cohort_id'}, ->
      this.resource('boot', {path: 'boots/:boot_id'}, ->
        this.resource('hub', {path: 'hubs/:hub_id'})
```